# Access Denied after import database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting following error after import a database in local mysql server within XAMPP.

**#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

This error is shown when I open **http://localhost/phpmyadmin**

I have check my.ini, config.inc etc files. There is no changes been made after import database. 
Which tables I need to examine for reset authentication

Comment: on which action you get this error ?

Comment: Hi Aman, none of my any applications (with mysql backend) working right now. I got this error on  phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

i think you have also imported the mysql.user table that's why all users overwrite.

You can try connection by creating a new user..

Comment: I have check whole imported dumb file, there is no any query with 'mysql.user'

Comment: May be there is another syntax. Check insert into user table command